# Проблема с переключением языка [mac]

Tags: mac

При переключении языка на mac, появляется всплывающее окно где можно мышкой выбрать нужный язык. Но есть у тебя курсор находится по центру экрана, то язык переключается обратно. Очень сильно бесит. Есть ли способы это пофиксить, я не нагуглил.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В настройках горячих клавиш есть пункты **Выбрать предыдущий источник ввода**, **Выбрать следующий источник ввода**... Они вот меню не показывают при переключении.

[image: Источники ввода в настройках Mac OS]

Comment: Они у меня и стояли по умолчанию, к тому же тут ничего добавлять или менять нельзя

Comment: @AndreyGrek Можно и добавлять и менять. Но для этого нужно знать основы AppleScript.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, надо погуглить. Я скриншот добавил, вот эту хрень хочу отключить